# "I jarred to life" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I understand the meaning of "to jar" (thank to the dictionaries) but "to jar to life" makes me confused and puzzled.

Is it something near to "sprang to life"?

You can meet this phrase in Google:

- [Keeping You a Secret by Julie Anne Peters](https://books.google.ru/books?isbn=0316025755): **I jarred to life**,releasing my gripon Courtney.
- [The Scene by R.M. Gilmore](https://books.google.ru/books?id=oV_gBwAAQBAJ): “D?” She touched my elbow, and **I jarred to life**. “Yeah?”

Comment: Yes, it's like "sprang to life." Suppose you're nodding off at a boring movie when suddenly something explodes in your kitchen. The sound *jars you back to life* (that is, back into wakefulness).

Comment: Is it an idiom or a regular expression?

Comment: Hard to say. It might be a little metaphorical, but its meaning is pretty much determined by the words "jar" and "life".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Jar*, as a verb, means “to have an unpleasant, annoying, or disturbing effect”.

"Jarred to life" means the same thing as "sprang to life" (Silenus's comment has a good example.)  In this case, *jar* is a synonym of *jolt*, *shake*, *startle*, *disturb* and *provoke*.